# Detect if CSS drop-down menu is close to browser edge and change alignment - fluid width

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, fluid

I currently have a pure CSS drop-down/mega menu which works fine. The layout is fluid (percentage based) and I'm also using media queries.

The issue I have is that I need to detect if a menu item `li` is near to the browser edge and change the `align` property using CSS.

I'm guessing that I'll need to use jQuery to achieve this but really don't know how.

Comment: i think you should try by your own first. Take a look at http://docs.jquery.com/ . But here is a clue: http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this. It's probably not elegant, but if an *li* is close to the left or top it will go pink. You should be able to complete the puzzle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Untitled 1</title>

<style type="text/css">
    ul{
    list-style:none;
    }
    li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:silver;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
        <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
        <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
        <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
        <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
    </ul>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <script type="application/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var items = new Array();
            var i;

            function paintPink(){
                $('ul > li').css('background-color','silver');
                for (i=1;i<=$('ul').children().length;i++){
                    if ((($('ul > li:nth-child(' + i + ')').offset().left) < 60) || (($('ul > li:nth-child(' + i + ')').offset().top) < 60)){
                        $('ul > li:nth-child(' + i + ')').css('background-color','fuchsia');
                    };
                };
            };

            $(window).load(paintPink);
            $(window).resize(paintPink);

        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the slow reply, I've been sidetracked by some other client work and I'll hopefully get back onto this very soon.